# python: code has no error but it does not output anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have written a class that takes in a text file as input and outputs a text file at the end. I get no errors when i run the code, but there is no output at the end. I have recently started with OOP, so I would be grateful if anyone can give me a hint.

and the 'test.txt' file contains these 4 sentences:

Mach das Licht an

Können Sie bitte die Tür öffnen

Reservieren Sie einen Platz in diesem Restaurant

Kannst du einen Song von Adele spielen

Comment: You don't call `formalized()`, `informalized()`, etc, so those lists will naturally be empty.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I edited the code. but i still get no output. sorry it might be an obvious issue, but I am new to oop and i cannot see that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have a better time composing this *not* using OOP.

Here's a reworking of your code to make those augmentation functions bare generator functions that `yield` augmented versions of phrases; you can then loop over each augmenter and `.extend()` their output into a list.

You can then plug in a separate function that reads phrases from a file and another that writes them out.

```
vowel_change = {
    "Nimm": "Nehmen",
    "Sieh": "Sehen",
    "Lies": "Lesen",
    "Stiehl": "Stehlen",
    "Gib": "Geben",
    "Brich": "Brechen",
    "Gilt": "Gelten",
    "Hilf": "Helfen",
    "Stich": "Stechen",
    "Stirb": "Sterben",
    "Triff": "Treffen",
    "Tritt": "Tretten",
    "Vergiss": "Vergessen",
    "Wirf": "Werfen",
}


def formalized(entry):
    first_word, rest = entry.split(" ", 1)
    if not (first_word.endswith(("en", "n"))) and not (entry.startswith(("Können", "Kannst"))):
        if first_word not in vowel_change:
            formalized_text = first_word + "en Sie " + rest
            yield formalized_text
        else:
            for key, val in vowel_change.items():
                if first_word in key:
                    formalized_text_vowel_changed = first_word.replace(key, val) + " Sie " + rest
                    yield formalized_text_vowel_changed


def informalized(entry):
    words = entry.split()
    first_word = words[0]
    if first_word.endswith(("en", "n")):
        if not entry.startswith(("Können", "Kannst")):
            if first_word not in vowel_change.values():
                informalized_text = entry.replace("en Sie", "e")
                yield informalized_text
            else:
                for key, val in vowel_change.items():
                    if first_word in val:
                        informalized_text_vowel_changed = (
                            first_word.replace(val, key)
                            + " ".join(words[1:2]).replace("Sie", "")
                            + " "
                            + " ".join(words[2:])
                        )
                        yield informalized_text_vowel_changed


def particle_bitte_addition(entry):
    if "bitte" not in entry.lower():
        words = entry.split()
        beginning_bitte = "Bitte " + words[0].lower() + " " + " ".join(words[1:])
        yield beginning_bitte
        end_bitte = entry + ", bitte"
        yield end_bitte


def particle_danke_addition(entry):
    if "danke" not in entry.lower():
        end_danke = entry + ", danke"
        yield end_danke


def kannst_added(entry):
    if entry.startswith("Können Sie"):
        koennen_replaced = entry.replace("Können Sie", "Kannst du")
        yield koennen_replaced


def koennen_added(entry):
    if entry.startswith("Kannst du"):
        kannst_replaced = entry.replace("Kannst du", "Können Sie")
        yield kannst_replaced


augmenters = [
    formalized,
    informalized,
    particle_bitte_addition,
    particle_danke_addition,
    kannst_added,
    koennen_added,
]

originals = [
    "Kannst du einen Song von Adele spielen",
    "Können Sie bitte die Tür öffnen",
    "Mach das Licht an",
    "Reservieren Sie einen Platz in diesem Restaurant",
]

for entry in originals:
    augmented = []
    for augmenter in augmenters:
        augmented.extend(augmenter(entry))
    print(entry, augmented)
```

This prints out e.g.

```
Kannst du einen Song von Adele spielen ['Bitte kannst du einen Song von Adele spielen', 'Kannst du einen Song von Adele spielen, bitte', 'Kannst du einen Song von Adele spielen, danke', 'Können Sie einen Song von Adele spielen']
Können Sie bitte die Tür öffnen ['Können Sie bitte die Tür öffnen, danke', 'Kannst du bitte die Tür öffnen']
Mach das Licht an ['Machen Sie das Licht an', 'Bitte mach das Licht an', 'Mach das Licht an, bitte', 'Mach das Licht an, danke']
Reservieren Sie einen Platz in diesem Restaurant ['Reserviere einen Platz in diesem Restaurant', 'Bitte reservieren Sie einen Platz in diesem Restaurant', 'Reservieren Sie einen Platz in diesem Restaurant, bitte', 'Reservieren Sie einen Platz in diesem Restaurant, danke']
```

EDIT: a `parse_file` replacement that also `yield`s phrases according to your original logic could be

```
def parse_file(filename):
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if extension == ".txt":
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line.split(',')[0]
    elif extension == ".csv":
        with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            next(data)
            for element in data:
                yield element[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('the file extension is not recognized.')
```

Plugging this all together, you could do

```
with open("output.txt") as outf:
    for entry in parse_file("input.txt"):
        for augmenter in augmenters:
             for augmented in augmenter(entry):
                  print(augmented, file=outf)
```

Comment: thank you very much. i see this approach is much easier

Comment: Glad I could help. I also added a `parse_file` generator replacement and an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling "parse_file()"

At the end of init:

```
self.parse()
```

and then call the other methods in the same way